# PHP preg_match_all nested too deeply

Tags: php, regex, multidimensional-array, nested, preg-match-all

I found a similar question here but wasn't exact to my scenario.
I'm relatively new to PHP but have read the manual for *preg_match_all*.

I'm parsing a page to find a date. It's always in the same format (E.g. **13 Apr 2012**).
This is my *preg_match_all* statement:

```
$eventDateRegex = '/[0-9]{2}\s[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}\s[0-9]{4}/';
preg_match_all($eventDateRegex, $parsedEvent, $eventDates[$i]);
```

*$i* is just an iterator because it's in a *for* loop.
I'm receiving the correct result in *$eventDates*, however, it seems to be nested one level too deeply.

My result is like this:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          0 => string '19 Apr 2012' (length=11)
          1 => string '24 May 2012' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          0 => string '21 Apr 2012' (length=11)
          1 => string '30 Jun 2012' (length=11)
```

Whereas I'd prefer it to be:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '19 Apr 2012' (length=11)
      1 => string '24 May 2012' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '21 Apr 2012' (length=11)
      1 => string '30 Jun 2012' (length=11)
```

Is this possible or is it just because of the way *preg_match_all* spits out a multi-dimentional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the result in the format you want.  The first level of indexes in the EventDates array is generated by your for-loop and your use of the index $i.  For example, the first element in the array

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          0 => string '19 Apr 2012' (length=11)
          1 => string '24 May 2012' (length=11)
```

is the correct array structure

```
array
          0 => 
            array
              0 => string '19 Apr 2012' (length=11)
              1 => string '24 May 2012' (length=11)
```

but in position 0 in eventDates because you passed $eventDates[0] as the matches array to the preg function.

Comment: Hi @msgmash.com, you're right about it loop iterator. But the problem still persists. The output of the array structure was gotten by doing a var_dump outside of the loop. It seems that preg_match_all is returning results that are nested too deeply. Within the same result-set, I have this:

      7 => 
        array
          0 => 
            array
              0 => '31 Aug 2012'
To retrieve a single date, I am currently required to do this:

    $eventDates[0][0][0]

I'm open to the fact that I may have misunderstood your answer?

Comment: You won't get the result you want because of the way that preg_match_all formats the array that holds the results.  This array is a multi-dimensional array where the first element is an array that holds all the strings matching the whole regexp.  Hence your first level index is the loop index, the second level is preg_match_all's first level index to the array that holds all string matches and the third level indexes into each matching string.  Unless you programmatically alter the array, there isn't an alternative.

Comment: Yeah I had a bit more of a think about it and came to terms with it. I'll just have to accept the 3D array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [T-Regx](https://t-regx) that never returns *an array of arrays*

```
$eventDateRegex = '\d{2} [A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{4}';
$eventDates[$i] = pattern($eventDateRegex)->match($parsedEvent)->all();
```

And that would return:

```
[
   ['19 Apr 2012', '24 May 2012']    // first $i
   ['21 Apr 2012', '30 Jun 2012']    // second $i
]
```

PS: Notice that that thanks to [T-Regx](https://t-regx) - `$eventDateRegex` doesn't have `/` delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

You can just restructure the array if you want to.

```
$arr = array(
            array(
                array('19 Apr 2012', '24 May 2012')
                ),
            array(
                array('21 Apr 2012', '30 Jun 2012')
                )
            );

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
    $arr[$i] = $arr[$i][0];

var_dump($arr);
```

You will get

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '19 Apr 2012' (length=11)
      1 => string '24 May 2012' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '21 Apr 2012' (length=11)
      1 => string '30 Jun 2012' (length=11)
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about doing this but I'm more concerned about efficiency and that would just be overkill.

Comment: Performance should be negligible unless you're doing this hundreds of thousands of times.

Comment: That's true. I'll be using reg_match_all only a few times so it shouldn't be a problem.